# Default and explicit constructors

Tags: c++, class

I have a simple question.

Can I do that?

```
class test {
    int x;

public:
    test();
    test(int x);
};
```

And in main I have:

```
test t;
t(2);
```

Supose I have a class test and first I declare the object t with default constructor but then I want to explicitly modify the value calling the explicit constructor.
Because I tried this and I get no match call for function (test) (int) and this make no sense.

Comment: You want assignment. `t = test(2);`.

Comment: @GManNickG Yessss, thank you!!! it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class declaration is fine, but

```
t(2);
```

isn't a constructor call, it tries to call a `void operator()(int)` overload of `test`, which isn't provided.

---

You probably simply meant to write

```
test t(2);
```

or using the compiler generated assignment operator

```
test t;
t = 2; // or t = test(2);
```

instead of

```
test t;
t(2);
```

Comment: But if I do that I recive: test t is previously declared in test t; error. So there exists a way of calling a explicit constructor after I called a default one?

Comment: @DariusIonut I didn't mean you should replace that line, but use the syntax in the variable declaration and omit the original. If you want to provide assignment overload the assignment operator, or provide an overload of the call operator `operator()` as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @DariusIonut No, you can't. A constructor is always called exactly ***once*** for any class instance.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: pedantic: with constructor forwarding, a constructor can be called more than once ;-)